# Get Shopping cart rule info in invoice PDF

Tags: invoice, shopping-cart-price-rules, pdf

I would like to use shopping cart rule information in the invoice PDF. For certain rules I want to add some information in the PDF. How can I get these values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the following to work:

```
$order_ov = get_object_vars($order); 
$couponcode = $order_ov['_data']['coupon_code'];
```

Comment: that is really odd the `$order->getCouponCode()` but if you have it working that is good news.

Answer (score 1):

```
$couponCode= Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(ORDERID)->getCouponCode();
```

You can then look up the cart rule info, using salesrule/rule model.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but it doesn't work. I've found the following to work: `$order_ov = get_object_vars($order); $couponcode = $order_ov['_data']['coupon_code'];` don't know if this is 'bad coding' or not, but it works.